# Disable Chrome headless logs (Got 1TB per day) in Selenium Using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I got a very strange problem. I'm running 15 Chrome headless using `selenium` and python. Everything is running well on my brand new nvme drive.

Except one big problem : chrome instances are writing 1TB per day cumulated on my nvme. The logs file are not stored (I mean I couldn't find them and my disk is only 250GB) but they are written to the disk according to iotop and smart monitoring.

I tried to disable the logs with multiple solutions (redirecting to /dev/null, enable logger for errors only) but I couldn't manage to stop the enormous IO on my drive. I'm not even sure that's I came from the logs, but I have write activity on my Google Chrome instances, I don't know what it could be.

**Do you have any idea about how I could reduce the write activity on my disk ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try these capabilities for chrome webdriver?

```
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
capabilities["goog:loggingPrefs"] = {"browser": "WARNING", "driver": "WARNING", "performance": "WARNING"}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try as soon as possible